# Regex recurses too often

Tags: python, regex, jython

I am trying to write a regex to match optionally quoted values (valid quotes are `"'` and `).
The rule is that the occurence of two quotes is an escaped quote.

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
(?P<quote>["'`])?(?P<value>(?(quote)((?!(?P=quote).)|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})*|[^\s;]*))(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)
```

And now in readable (with comments indicating what I think it does):

```
(?P<quote>["'`])?                   #named group Quote (any quoting character?)

    (?P<value>                      #name this group "value", what I am interested in
        (?(quote)               #if quoted 
            ((?!(?P=quote).)|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})* #see below
                                    #match either anything that is not the quote
                                    #or match 2 quotes
        |
            [^\s;]*         #match anything that is not whitespace or ; (my seperators if there are no quotes)
        )
    )

(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)               #if we had a leeding quote we need to consume a closing quote
```

It Performs fine for unquoted strings, quoted strings crash it with:

```
    match = re.match(regexValue, line)
  File "****/jython2.5.1/Lib/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

what do I do wrong?

**edit**: Example input => output(for capturing group 'value' (desired)

```
text    => text
'text'  => text
te xt   => te
'te''xt'=> te''xt   #quote=' => strreplace("''","'") => desired result: te'xt
'te xt' => te xt
```

**edit2**: while looking at it i noticed a mistake, see below, however I believe the above to be still a valid re +> it might be a Jython bug, however it still does not do what I want it to do: (very subtle difference, point moved out of the lookahead group

```
new:(?P<quote>["'`])?(?P<value>(?(quote)((?!(?P=quote)).|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})*|[^\s;]*))(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)
old:(?P<quote>["'`])?(?P<value>(?(quote)((?!(?P=quote).)|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})*|[^\s;]*))(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)
```

Comment: This is going to be messy with just regular expressions. You'd have an easier time using a combination of regular expressions and a state machine. Can you do that?

Comment: Have you thought about using something similar, like the `|` operator between different regexes? Example: `"\".*?\"|'.*?'"`

Comment: What happens when you have to interlocking sets of quotes, such as `'blah blah" blah' blah blah"`?

Comment: @JoelCornett: do you mean (regex quoted value)|(regex non quoted value)? I would have to write (almost) the same expression four times, once for every quoted version (3 Times), and once for the unquoted version. Furthermore I would have trouble extracting my value since I would have to check all the capturing groups if I am not mistaken

Comment: @ted: I'm not sure what you mean. Please update your question with in example input and example expected result.

Comment: @JoelCornett I wont try for `'blah " blah' blah"` when the script already crashes on `"blah"`. Besides my regex would then match `'blah " blah'` If I continue searching then I would finde a space wich I eat as a delimeter (seperate regex in the loop) and feed the rest (`blah"`) which would be completly matched. This would be fine since a string is only quoted if the first char is a quote, and besides it is a syntax error (should not cause a crash, should cause a warning but is fine without). my primary issue is to get that regex running

Comment: @ted: I'm using cPython 2.7.2 and your regex "runs" fine. It seems to  return some incorrect results, unfortunately. I got `'Hello` from `'Hello, George'`, for example.

Comment: @JoelCornett unfortunatly I am bound to use Jython, which is python 2.5 but thanks for the input. Why the regex only returns `'Hello` is a mystery to me

Comment: could you just use the csv module with an appropriate quotechar?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just stumbled over that, guess I could, but now it is the couriousness why this does not work. Just finding a workarround is one thing, knowing why another approach does not work is something different. I thought I won't put csv file parsing in here so that I get answers. You have a sharp mind to see what I am going for from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a bit of fiddeling:

```
good:(?P<quote>["'`])?(?P<value>(?(quote)((?!(?P=quote)).|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})*|[^;\s]*))(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)
bad :(?P<quote>["'`])?(?P<value>(?(quote)((?!(?P=quote)).|((?=(?P=quote)).){2})*|[^\s;]*))(?(quote)(?P=quote)|)
```

and no I don't understand the difference

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : in the end you will find a group like this `[^;\s]` before it was `[^\s;]`. while I agree that far that technically those two should behave the same on my system they don't. Remember I use **Jython 2.5** (It is build in into the application I have to use thus I can't upgrade) and got errors where you did not, but nice testscript I can check on monday if my regexes are the same under jython and might file a bug report then.

Comment: python 2, 3, pypy, jython produce the same result (no difference between 'good', 'bad') for the input I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, I recommend to be explicit and just write down all possibilities:

```
r = r"""
    ([^"'`]+)
    |
    " ((?:""|[^"])*) "
    |
    ' ((?:''|[^'])*) '
    |
    ` ((?:``|[^`])*) `
"""
```

When extracting matches you can use the fact that only one group of four will be populated, and simply remove all empty groups:

`````
r = re.compile(r, re.X)
for m in r.findall(''' "fo""o" and 'bar''baz' and `quu````x` '''):
    print ''.join(m)
`````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, given a string with 3 different types of quotes

> "Hello, sir", said the 'monkey', `nonchalantly`.

You want to extract the quoted values. In this case they would be:

> Hello, sir
>
> monkey
>
> nonchalantly

The following expression extracts these:

```
>>> expr = "\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)'|`(.*?)`"
```

Observe:

```
>>> s = """
"Hello, sir", said the 'monkey', `nonchalantly`. 
"""
>>> import re
>>> m = re.finditer(expr, s)
>>> for match in m:
...     print match.group()
...
('Hello, sir', None, None)
(None, 'monkey', None)
(None, None, 'nonchalantly')
```

Incidentally, your own regex appears to work on my version of python (cPython 2.7.2 on Mac OSX 10.7.4), but generates wrong results.

Comment: what does your regex do with `"te""xt","text"` ? i guess it yields `te""xt","text`(greedy little regex) and I don't know of a non greedy modifier, besides I need to do the escaping, I would like to use regex match and consume the string bit by bit from front to end and get `te""xt` and `text`

Comment: The `?` turns a greedy modifier into a nongreedy one.

Comment: @ted: This re would return `"te"`, `"xt"`, `"text"`.

Comment: I forgot about that, however this is still not quite what I want (see first comment)